# How to use Glide library in android to display image from url? Glide Usage

Tags: android, image, networking, httpresponse, android-glide

**EDIT**

If I try to use glide, and import an image ( https://mega.nz/#!nJ8yECaR!wHK3fz1xPEx9VMjTPuxzao6XDemAXy0T5s7KBUCsffs) the image button goes to the all screen, while the picture is the right position. And if I "click", the button see in all the screen.Anyone can tell me the right method step-by-step?

Comment: share your crash log with question

Comment: Where can I find it?

Comment: Try to Change extension from `.png` to `.jpg`

Comment: Is the size of the images too big?

Comment: post the full code for the xml file in which you are getting error

Comment: This question was changed completely. After accepting my answer that solve the original question, OP edited the question completely to a question that is to broad.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are running out of memory, you need to load the images into cache. [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) and [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) are great libraries for handling images.

With glide you will add the image like this:

```
GlideApp
.with(MyActivity)
.load(R.drawable.updatelog)
.centerCrop()
.into(myImageButton);
```

and with picasso you would load it like this:

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(R.drawable.updatelog)
.fit().centerCrop()
.into(myImageButton);
```

As @Nilu stated - the png is not loaded in a `ImageView` but you are still using png/images that uses memory to load.

That is why you are able to load 1 image but crashes when you load more images/png's because your application is running out of memory as your log cat suggest:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 56MB until OOM
```

I would suggest using a `ImageButton` then loading it with picasso or glide.

Comment: sir he is not adding image from url in imageview he is adding in button please read question again

Comment: @Nilu please see my edit. He is still adding images and if there is no more memory to load the images the application will crash (please see the log cat).

Comment: It works, but the whole screen goes to a button, while the image is lower size (btw it is in the right position).

Comment: Why did you unaccept my answer? It solved your problem did it not? The issue you're having with the size has nothing to do with this question! You should have asked a new question instead of editing your question completely.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an `ImageButton`. It is the preferred way.

Comment: With ImageButton, it crashes too

Comment: Kindly share the logcats.

Comment: This is not a answer and could've been added to the comment section

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert .PNG file to webp format by importing same image in Android Studio
For more details visit https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp.html

Answer (score 0):

you may  can't use `alpha` in background image so that may cause the problem .

Answer (score 0):

**Library Setup**

Add to your app/build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
  // Glide v4 uses this new annotation processor -- see https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
}
```

Make sure to create a `MyAppGlideModule` that simply extends from `AppGlideModule` and has the `@GlideModule` annotation.

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule

// new since Glide v4
@GlideModule
class MyAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule() { 
    
}
```

**Usage**

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load("URL")
    .into(ivImg)
```